# Output a variable from stored procedure that uses dynamic SQL and OPENQUERY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2019

I found [a guide](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/11/20/sql-server-results-of-dynamic-sql-into-a-variable/) to output the results of a dynamic SQL stored procedure into a variable, but the tricky part for my issue is that I'm using `OPENQUERY`, which makes using dynamic SQL a bit more challenging. The linked server has a database I'm trying to query called Global Shop Solutions and the provider is Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers.

The attempt below gives and error when I try to execute it:

> Incorrect syntax near '@LinkedServer'

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DateLastUsage] 
    (@Part nvarchar(50),
     @LinkedServer nvarchar(50),
     @DateLastUsage datetime2 OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(4000)

    SET @SQL = N'SELECT TOP 1 @DateLastUsage = DateLastUsage FROM OPENQUERY(@LinkedServer, ''SELECT MAX(date_history) DateLastUsage FROM v_inventory_hist WHERE part = ''@Part'' '' )'

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@LinkedServer nvarchar(50), @Part nvarchar(50), @DateLastUsage datetime2 output', @LinkedServer = @LinkedServer, @Part = @Part, @DateLastUsage = @DateLastUsage output
END

DECLARE @DateLastUsage datetime2
EXEC dbo.GSSDateLastUsage 'PartA', 'GSS', @DateLastUsage OUTPUT

SELECT @DateLastUsage
```

Comment: Please confirm that the linked server name is dynamic. Because if it is not, there is no need in any dynamic SQL. There is a way to call a linked server by passing parameters natively without any concatenation.

Comment: Best to include details about the linked server to avoid the questions you're raising against the answer below.

Comment: @DaleK Added the info you suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**As documented:**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks)

> `OPENQUERY` does not accept variables for its arguments.

So you'd need to use dynamic SQL for that also. Eg:

```sql
    set @SQL = N'
select top 1 @DateLastUsage = DateLastUsage
from openquery(' + QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer) + ', ''select max(date_history) DateLastUsage from v_inventory_hist where part = ''' + QUOTENAME(@Part, '''') + ''' '' )
';
```

Note the way `@Part` is embedded directly in the query, otherwise it also doesn't work/

---

But to be honest, it's not clear why you are using `OPENQUERY` anyway. You can query the linked server directly `from linkedserver...v_inventory_hist`. Now you can pass the parameters properly.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.DateLastUsage
    @Part nvarchar(50)
  , @LinkedServer sysname
  , @DateLastUsage datetime2 output
AS
    
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT @DateLastUsage = MAX(date_history) 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer) + '...v_inventory_hist
WHERE part = @Part;
';

EXEC @SQL,
   N'@Part nvarchar(50),
     @DateLastUsage datetime2 output',

     @Part = @Part,
     @DateLastUsage = @DateLastUsage output;
```

Or, if the linked server is also SQL Server, you can construct a `@proc` variable which points to `sp_executesql` on the remote server.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.DateLastUsage
    @Part nvarchar(50)
  , @LinkedServer sysname
  , @DateLastUsage datetime2 output
AS
    
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT @DateLastUsage = MAX(date_history) 
FROM v_inventory_hist
WHERE part = @Part;
';

DECLARE @proc nvarchar(1000) = QUOTENAME(@LinkedServer) + '..sys.sp_executesql';

EXEC @proc @SQL,
   N'@Part nvarchar(50),
     @DateLastUsage datetime2 output',

     @Part = @Part,
     @DateLastUsage = @DateLastUsage output;
```

Note also the change of data type to `sysname` and `nvarchar(max)1 respectively.

Comment: If I try to do what you suggest in the 2nd option, I get this error: `An invalid schema or catalog was specified for the provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "GSS".` 'GSS' is the real name of my linked server. It is not SQL Server based.

Comment: I did say it would only work if it was SQL Server. Unless you meant the option with `from linkedserver...v_inventory_hist` you might need to specify the database and/or schema explicitly.

Comment: Yes, that's the part I meant. I'm not sure how to fully qualify the object name to make that work. Also, your 1st option gives an error `Incorrect syntax near '98'` when I use @Part = '98-98202443'

Comment: Try `linkedserver..someschema.v_inventory_hist`. I'm not sure to be honest, never worked with MSDASQL drivers.